# How to speed up the moving process of a directory?

Tags: c#, performance, uwp

As StorageFolder does not have any function to move to another destination in the UWP API, I created my own which is this one:

```cs
        public static async Task MoveTo(this StorageFolder source, StorageFolder destination, string folderName, CreationCollisionOption creationCollisionOption = CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName, NameCollisionOption nameCollisionOption = NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName) {
          StorageFolder root = await destination.CreateFolderAsync(folderName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
          destination = root;

          foreach(StorageFile file in await source.GetFilesAsync()) {
            await file.MoveAsync(destination, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
          }

          foreach(StorageFolder folder in await source.GetFoldersAsync()) {
            await MoveTo(folder, destination, folder.Name);
          }
        }
```

Unfortunately, this code is really slow. It takes about 20-25 minutes to move 956 files and 25 folders.

I am sure that the issue is because of the fact that it is processed one by one and with `Task`.

Anyone would have any advice for me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Generally, using multiple threads to execute concurrently should be a possible way. Maybe you create a task for all the files in one folder. Then use `Task.WhenAll()` to run them together.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have tried with the Win32 API and it's quicker.
But MoveFileFromApp doesn't support folders so I had to re-write a function to move a directory. My function is not async and doesn't create any Task, in that case, how can it be even faster, because it's still taking almost 30 seconds to copy a folders with 950 files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get slightly better results using a parallel technique (I won't bother showing it here, because it's not that much faster) but you can do a *much* better job using the Win32 API [`MoveFileFromAppW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapifromapp/nf-fileapifromapp-movefilefromappw) if you P/Invoke it. This will work from a UWP so long as you have access rights (e.g. granted by the `FolderPicker`).

If the destination is on the same drive as the source, it will be almost immediate (it's a simple rename). If they're on different drives, you will need to do some logic to create each directory ([`CreateDirectoryFromAppW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapifromapp/nf-fileapifromapp-createdirectoryfromappw)) and then move the files. It will still be much faster than user `StorageFile`.

Comment: Hello! I have indeed tried this method with the runFullTrust capability but still experiencing issues.
MoveFileFromApp works perfectly for files, but when it comes to a directory, I get an error code 5 (Access denied).
What would cause this problem?

Comment: You don't need `runFullTrust` for this. Do you have permission to move the folder?

Comment: I think so. I'm trying to move the folder from my app's LocalCache folder to another app's package folder.
As I said earlier, it perfectly moves a single file from LocalCache to the other app's folder, but not a folder.
And I am using runFullTrust to keep a full access on the file system, especially because I need it for Xbox One as it doesn't support broadFileSystemAccess.

Comment: Xbox One doesn't support `runFullTrust` either - and that never applies to your "UWP" process on Desktop, anyway. It only applies to a separate process. What exactly are you trying to do? Moving files to another app's folder isn't really expected.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to move a file to another app's folder because it's where the add-ons are stored. It is the game Minecraft, and my app (MC Addons Manager) allows to install mods.
Even if runFullTrust isn't supported on Xbox, having my app as a game (Seems like Microsoft authorized it as is) allows to access the files.
And runFullTrust + broadFileSystemAccess used to work before.

Comment: Are you saying your app can run on a retail Xbox console and can access the files of another app (the Minecraft game)?

Comment: Yes, it indeed does.